# Packing number in finite-dimensional normed spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

I am working on a paper and quoted the following result from these [lecture notes](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/teaching/598/lec14.pdf).

[image: This theorem]

Where can I find a reference to this result either in a book or a paper, that I can cite?

*(I looked on the course website but to no avail...:0)*

Comment: What does $N$ stand for? What does $M$ stand for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson N and M are the $\epsilon$-covering and $\epsilon$-packing number of the set $\Theta$ with respect to a fixed norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inequalities (a) and (b) are more commonly used, which can be found in Lemma 5.7, [Wainwright (2019), "High-dimensional statistics: A non-asymptotic viewpoint"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E).

For Inequality (c), I haven't seen it in any books or papers.